# create Tree Structure in JSP using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

How Can I create a Tree Structure in JSP using JavaScript.

Thanks

Comment: probably the same way you would do it in static HTML with JavaScript, i.e. choose the Tree JS library and output the javascript to display a tree.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to build JSP tree structures from Java code. This is due to reduced browser dependencies. I have used only very basic Java script code to toggle nodes. [Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsptree-simple/) is the project.

Nodes are generated based on a parent child relationship. Data is retrieved from the MySQL database.